# Yii, set model value without using a hidden field

Tags: php, yii

I want to set the value of field in my model.  The field (source) is in the database but it doesn't have a field on the form to capture the data.  I want to set the value the field without creating a hidden form field.  Is that possible?

Thanks!

```
//in controller
public function actionTest()
                {
        $model=new TestForm();
        $src = 'hello';  
        $model->source($src);
        echo $model->source; // hello
        $this->render('_form',array('model'=>$model));    
                }
```

The form is then submitted and of course $source is not in the _POST because there is no field to capture $source

However I have set the value of $model->source but this value doesn't seem to persist because it is not saved in the database.

The only way to solve this i have found is to use a hidden field and pass in the value of $source to the form.

Is there a way to set $model->source and for this value to go in the database without going via the form?

Comment: See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model _Declaring Safe Attributes_ i think you should declare source attribute as unsafe. If you use hidden field, attacker could change it with firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set the value of `$source` when displaying the form (because e.g. that's when you have the required data in hand) then create a hidden input control. There's nothing wrong about it; you want to persist a non-default value in your model, and a hidden input element is the way to do that.

Comment: I guess I'm going to accept this answer.  I just thought it might be nice not to have to make a hidden element...

Comment: What if the value you want to use is sensitive like a users id? And you don't want to let a user try use a different ID. Is this still the best way?

Comment: @johnsnails: That question is a red herring. No matter if you put in a hidden field or not, data submitted by the client should *always* be assumed malicious until proven otherwise. They can add as many fields and give them whatever values they want; it's up to you to enforce security policy on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Well a form has to post somewhere and in Yii it's advised to post back to the same page.

I would do this way:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['NotificationLog']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['NotificationLog'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
        } else {
                  // set defaults
                  $model->source = 'hello';
            }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your rules function in the model class:

```
public function rules() {

    return array(
        .
        .
        .
        array('source', 'default', 'value' => 'hello'),
    );
}
```

Comment: What if you want the value to be the currently logged in users ID? Can you use that value using this method? never mind. I think this would work.
['source', 'default', 'value' => Yii::$app->user->id],

Answer (score 0):

use beforeSave in the class. refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/post.create#customizing-x-9x-and-x-11x-operations

Comment: You should provide full answer here, don't just post a link and think that's it. Try to write some code example.